# Delete table row from filtered ListObject

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete an entire row from a Table (ListObject), but I have issues adressing the Row.
Following code works prefect when the table is not filtered:

```
Sub loeschen()

If errorhandling Then On Error GoTo fehlerbehandlung

    ActiveCell.ListObject.ListRows(ActiveCell.Row - ActiveCell.ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Row).Delete

Exit Sub
fehlerbehandlung:
fehlermeldung

End Sub
```

Filtering is done by user in Excel, not VBA. Is there a direct way to delete a row or do I have to unfilter it? And if that's the case, how do I filter it again the same way (the user shouldn't notice anything, I'll apply `Application.ScreenUpdating`if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

You have to call the row this way

```
ActiveCell.ListObject.Range.EntireRow(ActiveCell.Row - ActiveCell.ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Row + 1).Delete
```

Even if filtered, the right row will be deleted. (Same thing for `.Select`)

Answer (score 1):

If it is already filtered, you can try this:

`ActiveSheet.ListObjects([Table_Name]).DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete`